# How I can give input to the 3d Convolutional Neural Network?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, video-processing

The 3d CNN works with the videos, MRI, and scan datasets. Can you tell me If I have to feed the input (video) to the proposed 3d CNN network, and train it's weights, how can I able to do that? as 3d CNN expect 5 dimensional inputs;

```
[batch size, channels, depth, height, weight]
```

how can I extract depth from the videos?

If I have 10 video of 10 different classes. The duration of each video is 6 seconds. I extract 2 frames for each second and it goes around 12 frames for each video.

**Size of RGB videos is 112x112 --> Height = 112, Width=112, and Channels=3**

**If I keep the batch size equals 2**

**1 video --> 6 seconds --> 12 frames (1sec == 2frames) [each frame (3,112,112)]**

**10 videos (10 classes) --> 60 seconds --> 120 frames**

So the 5 dimensions will be something like this; `[2, 3, 12, 112, 112]`

2 --> Two videos will be processed for each batch size.

3 --> RGB channels

12 --> each video contains 12 frames

112 --> Height of each video

112 --> Width of each video

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that seems to make sense if you're looking to use a 3D CNN. You're essentially adding a dimension to your input which is the temporal one, it is logical to use the `depth` dimension for it. This way you keep the channel axis as the feature channel (*i.e.* not a spatial-temporal dimension).

Keep in mind 3D CNNs are really memory intensive. There exist other methods to work with temporal dependent input. Here you are not really dealing with a third dimension (a 'spatial' dimension that is), so you're not *required* to use a 3D CNN.

---

Edit:

> If I give the input of the above dimension to the 3d CNN, will it learn both features (spatial and temporal)? [...] Can you make me understand, spatial and temporal features?

If you use a 3D CNN then your filters will have a 3D kernel, and the convolution will be three dimensional: along the two spatial dimensions (width and height) as well as the depth dimensions (here corresponding to the temporal dimensions, since you're using depth dimension for the sequence of videos frames. A 3D CNN will allow you to capture local ('local' because the perception field is limited by the sizes of the kernels and the overall number of layers in the CNN) spatial and temporal information.

Comment: Yes, I can use CNN+LSTM for learning spatial-temporal information but 3d CNN (such as I3D, ResNext (3d)) works fine with action recognition (UCF101) datasets.

Comment: Well, I couldn't get your point, if I want to learn spatial-temporal information out of my data which is in video format, If I give the input of above dimension to the 3d CNN, will it learn both features (spatial and temporal)?

Comment: Can you make me understand, spatial and temporal features? How can I extract both? Like if I am giving the third dimension to the image which is depth and that is for temporal information and other two dimension will be for  spatial information? isn't it?

Comment: I got your points, what should I need to do if I wanted to extract both spatial and temporal features (not locally)? How can I feed the video dataset to the 3d CNN? or should I convert my RGB videos to the optical flow (temporal information) and then pass it through LSTM to find the temporal features?

Comment: That's a limitation with CNNs the idea of locality, the perception field is finite or will need a huge network. This means your model will need to scale with the duration of your input sequences (depth) as well as the spatial dimensions of the images (height and width). Even with a LSTM your time dependency will be finite not for the same reason though, it will be because of the difficulty for the gradient to back-propagate.

Comment: Now, what should I need to do to get better accuracy on video dataset?

Comment: No I have not tried 3d CNNs, I was bit confused with the input shape of 3d CNN but now I got it. I am preprocessing on data, soon will train it.

Comment: I have kept another question, can you answer me?

Comment: If you found this answer helped solved your answer please consider accepting it. You have a considerable amount of stale - which have been given answers. I will take a look at your newly created question.

Comment: Yes, your answers really help me. Thank you <3

Comment: Glad it helped! On Stack Overflow you can "accept" one of the answers as valid by clicking on the green checkmark on the left of that question. It rewards users participating in the answering process and removes the actual question from the unanswered section of the forum.